# How to stop navbar-togglers to shift up and down when expanding and collapsing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I don't want my navbar-togglers to have animation when the dropdown menu is toggled and want them to stay at the same position. I want to fix the "Home" covered by logo. This code works fine on Google Chrome on my Mac but it will be broken on Chrome on Linux computer. I am using Bootstrap but I can't figure out where this animation is coming from by inspecting Chrome DevTools. Is there anyway I can fix it without affecting the layout when using Mac? Thank you.

```
nav.navbar {
    background-color: rgba(157, 0, 0, 0.9);
    min-height: 83px;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    top: 7px;
}


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../logo.png"></a>
    <button id="menuBarToggler" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div>
    <a id="phone" class="navbar-toggler" href="tel:021-256-9857"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>

    <button id="searchFromToggler" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchForm" aria-controls="searchForm" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle search form input">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="lunch-menu.html">Lunch (Dim sum)</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="dinner-menu.html">Dinner</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="tel:021-256-9857"><button id="navPhoneButton" class="btn btn-dark mx-2 my-sm-0 d-none d-lg-block" type="submit">Call Us</button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="https://www.foodhunter.co.nz/mobile/mmenu.php?ordering_rest_id=323#" target="_blank"><button id="navOrderButton" class="btn btn-dark my-sm-0" type="submit">Order Online</button></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="searchForm">
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: image to show how the expanded dropdown menu and toggler looks like]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

you can using `padding` instead of `min-height`,

```
nav.navbar {
    background-color: rgba(157, 0, 0, 0.9);
    padding:15px;
}
```

```css
nav.navbar {
    background-color: rgba(157, 0, 0, 0.9);
    padding:15px;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zREMh.png"></a>
    <button id="menuBarToggler" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div>
    <a id="phone" class="navbar-toggler" href="tel:021-256-9857"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></a>

    <button id="searchFromToggler" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchForm" aria-controls="searchForm" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle search form input">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="lunch-menu.html">Lunch (Dim sum)</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="dinner-menu.html">Dinner</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="tel:021-256-9857"><button id="navPhoneButton" class="btn btn-dark mx-2 my-sm-0 d-none d-lg-block" type="submit">Call Us</button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="https://www.foodhunter.co.nz/mobile/mmenu.php?ordering_rest_id=323#" target="_blank"><button id="navOrderButton" class="btn btn-dark my-sm-0" type="submit">Order Online</button></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="searchForm">
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It woked. Thank you so much!

Comment: You also welcome :) . Don't forgot [to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).